# Magento Importing product gives error

Tags: magento, import

I am new to magento.

I am facing problem while importing new products from magento import option

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`choiccgo_shop`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`) ON DEL)
```

Product is imported but stock,quantity is not updated

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It might be because column you trying to insert doesn't exist on table. I could give you two solutions.

How are you importing the products? Is that by

> System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow - Profiles -> Import All Products.

Solution 1: I would like to suggest you to import by a mass importer called [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). It has got good wiki page which gives you a elaborate description of the plugins and all other stuffs to import inside Magento.

Solution 2: [Update Quantity Separately](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-qty-in-magento-in-an-easier-faster-way/) - Click that link

Good Practices : It's always good practice use these these lines in the beginning of the SQL file which you're going to import

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;SET NAMES utf8;SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;
```

And at the end of the SQL file add these lines

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;
```